# In Episode VII, did the Starkiller base have any fauna?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

As we know from Episode VII, the First Order's Starkiller base was a very snowy and cold planet. Obviously though, it could sustain life as the First Order troops didn't wear suits while outside and also there was a huge forest nearby (all clearly seen in the trailers).

However, as far as I can remember from the movie we don't get to see any animals or native humanoids, so this got me wondering: **Is there any sort of native fauna on Starkiller base?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There was.  "The planet was initially scouted by snowtrooper teams who eliminated any native life forms that could have posed a threat to the extensive future excavation and construction project.  The ice planet soon became known as Starkiller Base, and became the unofficial headquarters of the First Order."

From: ["Starkiller Base", *Wikia*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Starkiller_Base)

Comment: So the answer is that there still is some native fauna - because there's no possible way we can believe that snowtroopers had good enough aim to kill every single animal.   Some must remain.

Comment: source: apparently from "Star Wars: The Force Awakens: The Visual Dictionary" per the wiki link. Ideally, the actual quote from the book rather than the wiki would be in the answer

Comment: After what happened on Endor, I can definitely see the Stormtroopers shooting *any* native fauna, just to be sure.